# Text Wrap not working with WPF RichtextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I have a WPF User Control with a RichTextBox in it. I am consuming this User Control in one the WPF pages. Alongwith it, I am using a FlowDocumentPageViewer with a ListView in it. Later on, I am assigning the data of ListView in the RichTextBox using a FlowDocument. Everything goes well but the wrap functionality does not work in it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999967/how-to-wrap-text-in-richtextbox-wpf/31002892#31002892 ...using textblock textwrapping you can wrap text in flowdocument.

Comment: @HeenaPatil I understand the example in the link. However, my case is a little complex. I am using following hierarchy of components:- 1)
      <FlowDocumentPageViewer>
             <FlowDocument> 
                     <BlockUIContainer>
                         <ListView>

Comment: @HeenaPatil I understand the example in the link. However, my case is a little complex. I am using following hierarchy of components:-
      <UserControl with RichtextBox></UserControl with RichtextBox>
The following FlowDocument is assigned to the above user control via code.
      <FlowDocumentPageViewer>
             <FlowDocument> 
                     <BlockUIContainer>
                         <ListView>
                              <GridView>
And the above GridView has the GridColumns. Now, When the ListView is inside the above nesting then the text wrap does not work.

Comment: plz add sample code here.

Comment: Please refer below description provided by @sharad kumar sharma

Answer (score 1):

On behalf of @Sumit (who asked the question)

below is the code snippet which is currently being used.

1) User Control with RichTextBox

[image]

2) Method to bind FlowDocument to RichTextBox

[image]

3)Consumer Page
[image]

4) Consumer Page Code behind
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose the problem for wrap functionality, I segregated the components being used in the current XAML code into different solutions.

Please refer the following description to understand the steps followed in the analysis:-

- A solution with List View having DataGrid (with two columns and multiple rows):- The wrap functionality was working in this solution.
- A solution with FlowDocumentPageViewer having FlowDocument with the ListView used in the above solution:- The wrap functionality was working in this solution.
- A solution with the User Control(referred from MultiLinha) and above FlowDocumentPageViewer. The wrap functionality was not working in this solution.

After isolating the components in this way, I observed that while integrating the **User Control** with **FlowDocumentPageViewer** the wrap functionality stopped working.

This was resolved when I put **Style** with property **Text Wrapping** set to **Wrap** for the FlowDocument itself.